# .show() not working after 'display :block'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

attached is my javascript and html.
in debug mode,  I can confirm that 'display: none' changes to 'display :block'
but I don't see popupEventForm form open up. 
Any ideas why?
Thanks,Peter

```js
function ShowEventPopup(date) {
  debugger;
  ClearPopupFormValues();
  $('#popupEventForm').show();
  $('#eventTitle').focus();
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id='calendar' style="width:65%"></div>
</div>


<div id="popupEventForm" class="modal hide" style="display: none;">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h3>Add new event</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form id="EventForm" class="well">
      <input type="hidden" id="eventID">
      <label>Event title</label>
      
      <input type="text" id="eventTitle" placeholder="Title here"><br />
      <label>Scheduled date</label>
      
      <input type="text" id="eventDate"><br />
      <label>Scheduled time</label>
      
      <input type="text" id="eventTime"><br />
      <label>Appointment length (minutes)</label>
      
      <input type="text" id="eventDuration" placeholder="15"><br />
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" id="btnPopupCancel" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Cancel</button>
    <button type="button" id="btnPopupSave" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary">Save event</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm guessing it's because you use both the hide class and display: none inline style

Comment: what other css does it have? has i been moved off screen / is it behind other elements on screen?  What is being clicked to trigger the function - is it a link / button that can reload the page?  Please create a [MCVE]

Answer (score 2):

You also have the bootstrap hide class included..

```
<div id="popupEventForm" class="modal hide" style="display: none;">
```

Change your js to this:

```
function ShowEventPopup(date) {
        debugger;
        ClearPopupFormValues();
        $('#popupEventForm').show().removeClass('hide');
        $('#eventTitle').focus();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the "hide" class from the modal. As well as you can use `.modal('show')` to open the modal

```
function ShowEventPopup(date) {
        debugger;
        ClearPopupFormValues();
        $('#popupEventForm').removeClass('hide');
        $('#popupEventForm').modal('show');
        $('#eventTitle').focus();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks everyone !    I didn't know  I am using a bootstrap modal . I found some good examples on W3 website.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using style "display:none" use $('#popupEventForm').hide();
and $('#popupEventForm').show();

Or you can use $('#popupEventForm').attr("display","block").